# Use inequality to bound an expectation

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, expected-value, central-limit-theorem

This is Exercise 3.1.1 part (a) from Amir Dembo's Note:

> Let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{n}$ for $X_{k}$ mutually independent such that $v_{n}=Var(S_{n})<\infty$. Show that if there exists $q>2$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}v_{n}^{-q/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|^{q}=0,$$ then $$v_{n}^{-1/2}(S_{n}-\mathbb{E}S_{n})\Rightarrow\mathcal{N}(0,1).$$

I have worked out most of the proof, but I got stuck in the end.

My attempt is to apply Lindeberg's Central Limit Theorem to $$\widehat{S}_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{n,k}$$ where $X_{n,k}:=v_{n}^{-1/2}(X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}).$

I have managed to show that $Var(\widehat{S}_{n})=1$ and $\mathbb{E}X_{n,k}=0$. However, I don't know how to show the Lindeberg's Condition that for each $\epsilon>0$, we have $$g_{n}(\epsilon):=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_{n,k}^{2};|X_{n,k}|\geq\epsilon]\longrightarrow 0\ \text{as}\ n\longrightarrow\infty.$$

The proof in the note works in this way:

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_{n,k}^{2};|X_{n,k}|\geq\epsilon]&=v_{n}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[(X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k})^{2};|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|\geq v_{n}^{-1/2}\epsilon]\\
> &\leq\epsilon^{2-q}v_{n}^{-q/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|^{q}\longrightarrow 0.
> \end{align*}

I have no problem with the first equality, which is just the expansion of $X_{n,k}^{2}$ and $|X_{n,k}|$, I have no problem with the convergence in the end since it is by hypothesis from the question.

**However, I don't really understand the inequality the solution claims.** I tired Chebyshev (or Markov, depending on the book), since this is the only inequality concerning with the expectation with indictor function, but I don't see how I can get this inequality.

Is there any other inequality I am missing?

Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

Okay I figured this out following Galton's hint, as follows:

By hypothesis, there exists $q>2$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}v_{n}^{-q/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|^{q}=0.$$

Fix such $q>2$, note that $2-q<0$, and then we can write for each $\epsilon>0$ that 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_{n,k}^{2};|X_{n,k}|\geq\epsilon]&=v_{n}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[(X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k})^{2};|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|\geq v_{n}^{\frac{1}{2}}\epsilon]\\
&=v_{n}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[(X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k})^{q}(X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k})^{2-q};|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|\geq v_{n}^{\frac{1}{2}}\epsilon]\\
&=v_{n}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[(X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k})^{q}(X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k})^{2-q};|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|^{2-q}\leq v_{n}^{\frac{2-q}{2}}\epsilon^{2-q}]\\
&\leq v_{n}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|^{q}|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|^{2-q};|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|^{2-q}\leq v_{n}^{\frac{2-q}{2}}\epsilon^{2-q}]\\
&\leq v_{n}^{-1}\cdot v_{n}^{\frac{2-q}{2}}\epsilon^{2-q}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|^{q}\\
&=\epsilon^{2-q}v_{n}^{-q/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|^{q}\longrightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Write $\mathbb{E}[(X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k})^{2};|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|\geq v_{n}^{-1/2}\epsilon] = \mathbb{E}[(X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k})^{q}(X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k})^{2-q};|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|\geq v_{n}^{-1/2}\epsilon]$. What happens if you apply $(2-q)$-th powers to both sides of $|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|\geq v_{n}^{-1/2}\epsilon$?

Comment: @Galton then we have $|X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}|\leq v_{n}^{-1+q/2}\epsilon^{2-q}$, but $2-q<1$, so we have $\leq$?

Comment: @Galton it is hard to write such an argument in the comment section. I will try to write a proof following your idea.

Comment: @Galton I think I figured it out. Would mind having a check? Also, you are really welcome to post an answer. you could directly copy what you said in the comment :) Thank you so much :)

Comment: Looks good to me! My $v_n^{-1/2}$ should have been $v_n^{1/2}$, good catch.

Comment: @Galton Thank you so much!

Comment: @Galton If you want to post an answer, please feel free to do so:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_k:=\left\lvert X_k-\mathbb E[X_k]  \right\rvert$. Then for each positive $R$, 
$$
Y_k^2\mathbf 1\{Y_k>R\}=Y_k^qY_k^{2-q}\mathbf 1\{Y_k>R\}\leqslant Y_k^qR^{2-q}.
$$
With $R=\varepsilon v_n^{1/2}$, we get the wanted inequality.